# Подсчет количества заказов сделанных каждым клиентом

Tags: sql

Есть 2 таблицы. В одной из них перечислены имена и айди клиентов...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В другой перечислены номера заказов и айди Клинта который этот заказ купил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать запрос так, чтобы мне посчитало сколько каждый клиент сделал заказов, т.е. клиент John сделал 3 заказа, Клиент Mike сделал 2 заказа, а клиент Luke сделал 4 заказа. Задачу решаю на тренажёре https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select u.User, count(uo.OrderID) from user_order as uo left join users as u on uo.UserID=u.UserID group by uo.UserID
```

Вместо user_order и users соответствующие названия ваших таблиц.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы мне очень помогли